# 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for '', no extension method '' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<>' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I'm getting this error in a controller.

I call a `IEnumerable` service and I'm trying to use it in a controller, but I'm getting this error.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    var userList = new List<User>();
    userList.Add(new User()
    {
        Email = "testc@test.com",
        Enabled = true,
        PhoneNumber = "555-555-5555",
        Username = "test"
    });
    userList.Add(new User()
    {
        Email = "user@domain.com",
        Enabled = true,
        PhoneNumber = "317-455-5555",
        Username = "anotheruser"
    });

    return userList;
}

public ActionResult Details()
{
    var user = _userService.GetUsers();
    var model = new UserViewModel()
    {
        UserName = user.Username,
        Enabled = user.Enabled
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

I expect to get user info from Details action in controller to display in view and this is the error message I get.

Answer (score 2):

Your `user` variable is actually a *list* of users, yet you're attempting to access properties on the actual user instance, not the list. In other words, you need to enumerate for the list of users:

```
var users = _userService.GetUsers();
var model = new List<UserViewModel>();
foreach (var user in users)
{
    model.Add(new UserViewModel
    {
        UserName = user.Username,
        Enabled = user.Enabled
    });
}
```

Or more simply:

```
var model = _userService.GetUsers().Select(user => new UserViewModel
{
    UserName = user.Username,
    Enabled = user.Enabled
});
```

The LINQ `Select` method enumerates the collection and applies the lambda to each item returning a new list composed of the return values of the lambda.